# Postgresql generate_series of months

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, generate-series, set-returning-functions

I'm trying to generate a series in PostgreSQL with the generate_series function. I need a series of months starting from Jan 2008 until `current month + 12` (a year out). I'm using and restricted to PostgreSQL 8.3.14 (so I don't have the timestamp series options in 8.4).

I know how to get a series of days like:

```
select generate_series(0,365) + date '2008-01-01'
```

But I am not sure how to do months.

Answer (score 29):

```
select DATE '2008-01-01' + (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,11))
```

**Edit**

If you need to calculate the number dynamically, the following could help:

```
select DATE '2008-01-01' + (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,month_count::int))
from (
   select extract(year from diff) * 12 + extract(month from diff) + 12 as month_count
   from (
     select age(current_timestamp, TIMESTAMP '2008-01-01 00:00:00') as diff 
   ) td
) t
```

This calculates the number of months since 2008-01-01 and then adds 12 on top of it.

But I agree with Scott: you should put this into a set returning function, so that you can do something like `select * from calc_months(DATE '2008-01-01')`

Comment: I made the following out of what you suggested:

`SELECT to_char(DATE '2008-01-01' + (interval '1 month' * generate_series(0,56)), 'Mon-YY') AS months`

The question is now, how to calculate 56 instead of statically defining it in the query above. 56 is the number of months since Jan 2008 + 12.

Comment: `select ((extract (year from current_date + interval '12' month) - 2008) * 12) + 
        (extract (month from current_date + interval '12' month) - 1)` will give you the right number of months.

Comment: I think it's time you wrote a function in plsql or plpgsql

Answer (score 9):

You can interval generate_series like this:

```
SELECT date '2014-02-01' + interval '1' month * s.a AS date
  FROM generate_series(0,3,1) AS s(a);
```

Which would result in:

```
        date         
---------------------
 2014-02-01 00:00:00
 2014-03-01 00:00:00
 2014-04-01 00:00:00
 2014-05-01 00:00:00
(4 rows)
```

You can also join in other tables this way:

```
SELECT date '2014-02-01' + interval '1' month * s.a AS date, t.date, t.id
  FROM generate_series(0,3,1) AS s(a)
LEFT JOIN <other table> t ON t.date=date '2014-02-01' + interval '1' month * s.a;
```

Comment: Could you please share some more details about on how the first solution is working?

Answer (score 6):

You can interval [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html) like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(months, 'YYYY-MM') AS "dateMonth"
FROM generate_series(
    '2008-01-01' :: DATE,
    '2008-06-01' :: DATE ,
    '1 month'
) AS months
```

Which would result in:

```
 dateMonth 
-----------
 2008-01
 2008-02
 2008-03
 2008-04
 2008-05
 2008-06
(6 rows)
```

Comment: But BEWARE of ends of months! ```SELECT TO_CHAR(months, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "dateMonth"
FROM generate_series(
    '2008-01-31' :: DATE,
    '2008-06-30' :: DATE ,
    '1 month'
) AS months```  will generate series of `"2008-01-31"
"2008-02-29"
"2008-03-29"
"2008-04-29"
"2008-05-29"
"2008-06-29"`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you only need months, you **could** do:

```
select extract(month from days)
from(
  select generate_series(0,365) + date'2008-01-01' as days
)dates
group by 1
order by 1;
```

and just parse that into a date string...

But since you know you'll end up with months 1,2,..,12, why not just go with `select generate_series(1,12);`?

Comment: because postgres ("MM") convert into 01, 02, 03 not 1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

In the `generated_series()` you can define the step, which is one month in your case. So, dynamically you can define the starting date (i.e. 2008-01-01), the ending date (i.e. 2008-01-01 + 12 months) and the step (i.e. 1 month).

```
SELECT generate_series('2008-01-01', '2008-01-01'::date + interval '12 month', '1 month')::date AS generated_dates
```

and you get

```
1/1/2008
2/1/2008
3/1/2008
4/1/2008
5/1/2008
6/1/2008
7/1/2008
8/1/2008
9/1/2008
10/1/2008
11/1/2008
12/1/2008
1/1/2009
```