# Creating a table of last 12 month in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a table that looks like this (a table of the last 12 months)

```
month, year
10, 2016
9, 2016
8, 2016
7, 2016
6, 2016
5, 2016
4, 2016
3, 2016
2, 2016
1, 2016
12, 2015
11, 2015
```

The code I have looks something like this:

```
select date_part('month', current_date) as order_month,
select date_part('year', current_date) as order_year
union all
select date_part('month', current_date - interval '1 month') as order_month,
select date_part('year', current_date - interval '1 month') as order_year
union all
...
```

Is there a more concise way of writing this, rather than using 11 unions?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/7450515/1741542 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/14113469/1741542 helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`generate_series(start, stop, step)` will be useful such that

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT('month' FROM d) AS month,
    EXTRACT('year' FROM d) AS year
FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES(
        now(),
        now() - interval '12 months',
        interval '-1 month'
    ) AS d
;
```