# What's exactly operator to compare between `bigint` and `date` in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

My story evaluated from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49729371/revisions):

I created a function create dynamic partition table with Table_Year_Month format such as table_2018_04, table_2018_05 .... The arguments of creation partition function are `bigint` such as `create_partition_function(1518164237,1520583437) ;`. After that I convert bigint to date to can get **`year`** and **`month`** from timestamp. But the check function `( check(timestamp >= date))` don't work

I can't compare `bigint` >= `date` in sql. What's operator can compare their?

I tried convert timestamp to datetime with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function of sql but don't work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_partition_function( DATE, DATE )
returns void AS $$
DECLARE
    create_query text;
    index_query text;
BEGIN
    FOR create_query, index_query IN SELECT
            'create table user_event_firebase_'
            || TO_CHAR( d, 'YYYY_MM' )
            || ' ( check( timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date,'%Y %M %D' )'''
            || TO_CHAR( d, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
            || ''' and timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date,'%Y %M %D' ) '''
            || TO_CHAR( d + INTERVAL '1 month', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
            || ''' ) ) inherits ( user_event_firebase );',
            'create index user_event_firebase_'
            || TO_CHAR( d, 'YYYY_MM' )
            || '_time on user_event_firebase_' 
            || TO_CHAR( d, 'YYYY_MM' )
            || ' ( timestamp );'
        FROM generate_series( to_timestamp($1), to_timestamp($2), '1 month'::interval ) AS d
    LOOP
        EXECUTE create_query;
        EXECUTE index_query;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

p/s : `bigint` and `date`are data type in sql.

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "2018-02-09"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "create table user_event_firebase_2018_02 ( check( timestamp >= bigint '2018-02-09' and timestamp < bigint '2018-03-09' ) ) inherits ( user_event_firebase );"
PL/pgSQL function create_partition_function(date,date) line 21 at EXECUTE
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Please wait me a second ...

Comment: Why do you want a comparison between values like April 10th, 2018 and 12345678909876?

Comment: just remove `bigint` - `'2018-02-09'` would probably be recognized as date

Comment: Is the `timestamp` field actually a `bigint` by any chance? Otherwise why would there ever be a cast of date to bigint?

Comment: I updated the question more detail.

Comment: Show us the complete `create table` statement. But a column named `timestamp` that is in fact a `bigint` is highly confusing. Why don't you use a proper `timestamp` data type to store a timestamp?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In my opinion, If I use `timestamp` data type, I would be consider to timestamp with out timezone and timestamp with timezone. `Bigint` can store timestamp exactly because timestamp is integer. That's right?

Comment: @eurotrash: How to cast ?

Comment: `timestamp without time zone` is also storing the timestamp "exactly", no conversion is taking place.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Sorry. I don't think the problem use `timestamp without time zone` instead of `bigint` have relation in my question. It's out of box. We can disscuss the problem in difference question. Thank you

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is certainly not going to work, it doesn't exist in Postgres.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert date/timestamp to seconds using

```
SELECT extract(epoch from '2016-05-03'::date)
--result: 1462233600

SELECT to_timestamp(1462233600)::date;
--result: '2016-05-03'
```